# Cisco Switch - Enable Telnet using HTTP

Tags: cisco, https, http, switch, telnet

I'm trying to automate the configuration process of a **Cisco switch (SG-300)**.
I was able to automate everything I need using telnet, but the last issue I still have is to enable telnet itself.

For now I enable it using the web interface and my plan was to call an API method for login, get a token, then use it to call another method that enables telnet. For this I tried inspecting the network for REST/SOAP API calls but nothing is clear and all the documentation I found specifies using the web interface exclusively. Is there any approach to this that doesn't involve UI automation?

Note: only HTTP and HTTPS are enabled by default.

[image: only HTTP and HTTPS are enabled by default.]

Comment: In this millennium you should be using ssh rather than clear text telnet.

Comment: AFAIK this is entry level switch and IMHO do not support REST/SOAP API. All configs are to be done via command line and/or web interface

Comment: @RomeoNinov can I access the switch via http from the command line like I do using telnet or ssh?